# RabbitMQ cluster fail-over issue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Created Cluster with two rabbitMQ nodes. Configuration is as below for rabbit1 and rabbit2 nodes.

```
1> CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setAddresses("rabbit1:5672,rabbit2:5672");
```

2> node types
rabbit1 - disc node
rabbit2 - ram node
3> producer and consumer programs sits on rabbit2 node(ie> ram node)

```
4> Producer sample code -
String QueueName = "Queue.";
for(int m=0; m<50000; m++){
    // send message
    System.out.println(this.rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getHost());
    this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(m);
    /*Thread.sleep(100);*/
}

5> consumer code -
String QueueName = "Queue.";
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Consumer running host : " + this.connectionFactory.getHost());
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(this.queueName);
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new TestMessageHandler(this.connectionFactory.getHost()), new JsonMessageConverter())); 
    container.start();
}

TestMessageHandler class sample code-

    public TestMessageHandler(String hostName){
        System.out.println("Host: " + hostName);
        this.hostName = hostName;
    }

    // Handle message
    public void handleMessage(int message) {
        System.out.println("handleMessage Host: " + this.hostName);
        System.out.println("Int : " + message);
    }

6> Each node executed below policy
cmd> rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "^Queue\." "{""ha-mode"":""all""}"

7> Started producer and consumer simultaneously. Could see host name as "rabbit1" then stopped "rabbit1" node with "rabbitmqctl stop_app" command to test fail-over scenario. Then got the below error

    WARN  [.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer]: Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
    com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; reason: {#method<connection.close>(reply-code=541, reply-text=INTERNAL_ERROR, class-id=0, method-id=0), null, ""}
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:678)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:668)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:624)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:598)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:96)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:523)
    INFO  [.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer]: Restarting Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-5CJ3YJYfMZDnJOnXsds6_Q], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@192.168.97.70:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

after this warning, again am getting host name as "rabbit1" only. actually it should be "rabbit2" as per my understanding but its not happening.

    So, here are my Queries -

        1> Why am getting host name as "rabbit1" even after stopping?
        2> To test the fail-over do we require any load balancer?
        3> If my steps are wrong for testing fail-over case, please provide steps for the same?
        4> How to distribute queues/messages to particular node, as below, 1-500 messages/queues to node1, 501-1000 messages/queues to node2, etc.
        5> Please let me know is there any other approach to test fail-over scenario?
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What do you mean by `getting host name as "rabbit1" only`? On the producer side, it's your responsibility to catch the exception and retry (you can use a `spring-retry` `RetryTemplate` if you wish). The consumer will automatically reconnect, and fail over to Rabbit2 automatically. You don't distribute messages to a particular node; Rabbit figures out which node is the current master for a particular queue.

Comment: after stopping the rabbit1(host name where one rabbitmq node is running in cluster) node, am printing host name in consumer and producer end. As we have stooped rabbit1 next time it has to print "rabbit2" as host name right?

Comment: What do you mean "printing" please describe the exact APIs you are using.

Comment: Please find consumer code - 
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
container.setQueueNames(this.queueName);
container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new TestMessageHandler(this.connectionFactory.getHost()), new JsonMessageConverter())); 
container.start();

 public class TestMessageHandler  {
 private String hostName;
 public TestMessageHandler(String hostName){ ---} 
 public void handleMessage(int message) {
  System.out.println("Host: " + this.hostName + " -- " + message);
 } 
}

Comment: new TestMessageHandler(this.connectionFactory.getHost()); This is only done once during handler instantiation - it has nothing to do with what rabbit you are connected to. Turn on DEBUG logging and you'll see the switch.

Comment: Thanks for the response Russell. 
am new to this RabbitMQ and Spring AMQP. Could please let me know where do I Turn on DEBUG logs? Do you mean log folder?

Comment: Consult the documentation for your logging subsystem - if you are using log4j, turn on DEBUG for category `org.springframework.amqp`.